# Grain of factless fact table

Tags: sql-server, dimensional-modeling

Designing a factless fact table in sql server 14. Should be quite simple, yet..: I have the need to check the amount of visits per day/client/team/status.
Aside from this amount of visits, i need to track the amount of actions done at every visit.

```
            SELECT [VISITS_PK]
                  ,[PERIOD_SK]
                  ,[CLIENT_SK]
                  ,[TEAM_SK]
                  ,[STATUSS_SK]
                  ,[ACTIONS_SK]
              FROM [dbo].[FACT_VISITS]
```

Will return

```
              VISITS_PK PERIOD_SK   CLIENT_SK   TEAM_SK STATUSS_SK  ACTIONS_SK
              1 20160515    1   1   1   1
              2 20160515    1   1   1   2
              3 20160515    1   1   1   3
              4 20160515    2   2   1   1
              5 20160515    2   2   1   2
```

Summary: 2 visits are done, 5 actions are done in total.

Tracking the amount of actions allows me to use COUNT, yet if i want to not take into account the actions and just see how many visits i got in total, do i need another fact table with another grain? I'd rather use one fact table as the amount of visits is in fact just more aggregated.

Edit: The actions_sk contains a link to a dimension table with detailed informations on the performed actions. the first 3 lines are one visit with 3 actions, the 2 last lines are one visit with 2 performed actions.

Comment: Why do you say the sample data shows two visits, when every row has a different VISITS_PK?   That to me indicates every row is from a different visit.

Comment: I edited my post, the first 3 lines are one visit with 3 actions performed at the client, the 2 last lines are one visit with 2 performed actions.

Comment: The reason it's called VISITS_PK is because the core of this table would be to get the amount of visits, but the amount of actions performed at each visits also needs to be known, although it's not the main question. So i guess it's bad naming to call the table visits and visits_pk as key name, as the lowest level is the actions performed.

Comment: Yes the names you chose misled me about the data.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a row for every action, just have one row per visit, with the SUM of the actions in that visit:

```
          VISITS_PK PERIOD_SK   CLIENT_SK   TEAM_SK STATUSS ACTIONS
          1         20160515    1           1       1       3
          2         20160515    2           2       1       2
```

**EDIT** based on new understanding of your data:

Ok, I would change the table name to Fact_Actions, since that is the lowest level of granularity, and Make visits a SK, like so:

```
          VISITS_SK PERIOD_SK   CLIENT_SK   TEAM_SK STATUSS_SK  ACTIONS_PK
          1         20160515    1           1       1           1
          1         20160515    1           1       1           2
          1         20160515    1           1       1           3
          2         20160515    2           2       1           4
          2         20160515    2           2       1           5
```

Now you can count Actions by counting rows, and count Visits by counting DISTINCT Visits_SK values.

Comment: That removes the information about the actions, i see now i forgot to put _SK behind STATUS_SK and ACTIONS_SK, but they are necessary to determine which actions happened on the visits. Removing this information is not an option.